# java.util.NoSuchElementException Not printing desired output

Tags: java, exception

I'm writing a Java program to try to parse a text file and store the contents of it in a matrix. The following is my Java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Viterbi
{        
String[][] gmatrix = new String[50][4];
float[] pmatrix = new float[50];

public Viterbi(String filename)
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
        String currentline;
        StringTokenizer st;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

        while((currentline = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            st = new StringTokenizer(currentline, ";");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                    {                                               
                        gmatrix[i][j] = st.nextToken();
                        System.out.println("i --> " + i + " j--> " + j + ": " + gmatrix[i][j]+"\t");                          
                    }

                }
            }                                                     
        }
        for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
                System.out.print(gmatrix[i][j]+"\t");
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if(br != null)
                br.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Viterbi v = new Viterbi("rules.txt");
}
}
```

And here's the contents of the text file:

```
S;a;S;0.6
S;b;X;0.4
X;c;$;0.1
X;X;$;0.9
```

I want the output to be displayed in the gmatrix as:

```
S a s
S b X
X c $
X X $
```

But for some reason I get the following output and exception:

```
i --> 0 j--> 0: S   
i --> 0 j--> 1: a   
i --> 0 j--> 2: S   
i --> 0 j--> 3: 0.6 
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at Viterbi.<init>(Viterbi.java:27)
at Viterbi.main(Viterbi.java:62)
```

How can I print the correct output as desired?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are only calling `hasNextToken()` once at the start of the `while` condition. **You need to call `hasNextToken()` as many times as nextToken(), to make sure that `nextToken()` will work**. The reason you don't have any more tokens on the line is that there are only 4 tokens per line (apparently) but you have two for loops that will try to call `nextToken()` a total of **50*4=200** times.

Alternatively to how you are doing this: you could just split the `currentLine` on ";" with the `split()` method and then loop through the returned `String[]` elements.

Comment: I don't get get it. Can you modify my code and explain please?

Comment: Sorry if I'm pushing but can you explain how to do with the split() method?

Comment: Can you please explain on how to do with the split() method?

Answer (score 0):

In your first while loop, you are actually trying to populate the whole `gmatrix` by parsing a single line of the input file. This is not what you expect. Since there are only 4 tokens in the first line, you get the exception when you are trying to call `st.nextToken()` to get the next (non-existing) token when the program is trying to get `gmatrix[1][0]`.

To correct your code, you should check and read a new input line in your first `for(int i = ...)` loop, and remove the 2 out-most `while` loops.

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; ...){
    // check if there is another line in input;
    // tokenize a line of input;
    for(int j = 0; ...){
        // get a token and populate one element in gmatrix;
    }
}
```

Instead of using the two `while` loops.

Comment: I don't get what you say. Can you please modify my code and explain?

Comment: I made the following change in my code: `for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
            {
             while((currentline = br.readLine()) != null)
             {
              st = new StringTokenizer(currentline, ";");
              for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
               gmatrix[i][j] = st.nextToken();
             }
            }`

Comment: But i get the following output: `X X $ 
null null null 
null null null 
null null null 
null null null `

Comment: You don't need your `while` loop any more. Just check if there is a new line in the outer `for`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get a clear picture of what you're trying to say. Can you please modify my code and explain?